# crash while signing in with google plus in ios 9

Tags: ios9, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am using google plus to sign in but when we come across [signIn authenticate] line the app crashes giving an error [__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.Help required urgently.Thanks in advance.